# Java dynamic Collection objects

Tags: java, arrays

For our programming assignment we have to ask the user for a Region Name and the statitics (integers) of that region we have to associate the integers with the Region Name and we have to be able to create multiple regions this is what I got so far lost as to what to do next Where I am confused is we have to call all the Regions the user has made Region A, Region B, Region C, then the user will select a Region from the list let's say Region A then we must print the integers associated with Region A Example Region A contains integers {12,3,6,8]

```
            ArrayList<String> regions = new ArrayList<String>();

            System.out.print(" Enter Region to Add to List: ");
            regionName = keyb.nextLine();
            keyb.nextLine();
            regions.add(regionName);
            System.out.printf(" Enter Data for %s: " ,regionName);
            regionData = keyb.nextLine();
            String[] reg_Values = regionData.split(" ");
            double[] reg_DoubleValues = new double[reg_Values.length];
            double num;
            for (int i=0; i<reg_Values.length; i++)
            {
                num = Double.parseDouble( reg_Values[i] );
                reg_DoubleValues[i] = num;
                System.out.print(reg_DoubleValues[i]);

            }
            System.out.println();
```

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. What is confusing you?

Comment: what confuses me is assigning the integers the user entered to the region name Example: Region A contains the integers 12, 4, 6, 3, 8 | Region B contains the integers 3 7 11 2 5, then calling all the Regions the user has made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need an Hashmap, or a key value pair collection. 
Providing that the regions are unique.

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>>
```

**Or**

```
HashMap<Region,List<Integer>>
```

Or

create a `Region` class, and have a composition of `List<Integer>`.

Like so:

```
public class Region
{
  List<Integer> integers;
  String regionName;
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating a `Region` class to hold the data for each particular region. This will make the code *much* easier to manage.

```
class Region {
    String name;
    String[] otherInfo;
    double[] otherOtherInfo;

    ...
}
```

You would then simply have a `List` of `Region` instances, which you can create as the user enters information about each region.

Comment: I could create a region class but what confuses me about that is we have to print the Regions the user has made Region A, Region B, Region C, and when they enter in the Region's name from the list then we must print the values associated with the Region Example Region A contains integers [12,3,6,8] and I can not figure out how to call all the Regions and then call the integers associated with that region

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use `Map/HashMap` to hold the region and statistics as below:

```
   Map<String, double[]> regionStatisticsMaps = new HashMap<String, double[]>();
```

Now you can place the value as :

```
   regionStatisticsMaps(regionName, reg_DoubleValues);
```

Comment: @A.R.S.: I was updated already. By the time I was updating it, got your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

you  need a **key value pair**. in **java API** terms you need a **Map** .

```
   Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

mind you that, if you need insertion order use LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap as HashMap doesnt maintain any order.

```
   Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
```